# Calculate complex integral, residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

I will be very glad for checking out my solution as I get different results compared to answers.

> $$I=\int\frac{1}{z(1-e^z)}$$

and we will integrate it on closed curved with following vertexes : $w_0=-i;w_1=-1;w_2=7+8i;w_3=-7+8i;w_4=1$
From what I see we will have $2$ singularities : $0$ and $2\pi i$. $$$$ $0$ will be pole of order $2$ and $2\pi i$ will be pole of order $1$.
Using residue theorem we know that $$I=2\pi i (ind(0)\cdot Res(f,0)+ind(2\pi i) Res(f,2\pi i)) = 2\pi i (-Res(f,0)+Res(f,2\pi i))$$
Now lets calculate residues.
$$Res(f,0) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(z^2\cdot \frac{1}{z(1-e^z)})'=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$Res(f,2\pi i) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 2\pi i}\frac{z-2\pi i}{z(1-e^z)}=\frac{-1}{2 \pi i}$$

To sum up $I =2 \pi i (-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{2 \pi i})$
While answers claim that this should be equal $-\pi i$, like they didn't take into account $Res(f,2\pi i)$. Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, they are straight lines. Curve is closed around $0$ and $2 \pi i$

Comment: OK.  The comtour is comprised of two closed curves.  The one enclosing $2\pi i$ is oriented counter.clockwise; the one enclosing $0$ is oriented clockwise.